# Scheduler resources with aliases

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

You all can see Kendo Resources example [there](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources). It's very simple — you just got an array with options, which Kendo knows — `color`, `text` and then bind them by `value`.

Now imagine another example — we have a more complex datasource in this format:

```
{ status: "Busy", value: 1, url1: "/img/overlay_icon_busy.jpeg", url2: "/img/icon_busy.jpeg"}
```

As you can see, there's only familiar to Kendo is a `value` field.
This source is a common for appointment template and for editor template. `text` and `url2` we shall use for editor (hello again, Multiselect!), `url1` must be used for template to show some overlay icon.

Problem is that I don't know how to bind this things as resource and make them work — I've never seen something like this. Can it be done with Kendo and how?

---

Update: maybe this image will help to understand what I'm trying to do.
[image: scheme]

Comment: Too dumb to imagine the view bro, please enlighten us with some image about how the UI should be..

Comment: According to your requirements in total you have to build 3 templates, 1 for event list in scheduler, 1 for event editor and another 1 for dropdown template. You should read their [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler) to achieve this.

Comment: I have templates, but I don't know, how to bind — there's no familiar properties for kendo.

Comment: Because this take a lot of work, I prefer you show us what kind of approach you have code so far.

Comment: You should see their documentation about `editable.template`, and `eventTemplate` and your resource should be bound normally to scheduler. no customization needed for resource setting. All you need is template and right schema model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem using next approach. 
First, I've declared datasource, and then just wrapped it in method, which accepts ID. 
And in a template I wrote:

```
<div class="pre" style="background: url(#: intToStatus(status).img #)"></div>
```

And it works!